# Log4j: How I can change LoggingEvent class for Logger

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to extend LoggingEvent class from log4j (I want to display **thread id** instead **thread name**) and keep Logger default class.

How I can assign my own LoggingEvent class to existing Logger class??

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `PatternLayout` to accomplish logging the ThreadId. See http://java.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/javaee-l/thread-id-in-log4j-logs-2926542

Comment: But I think thread id isn't the same on LoggingEvent object that in the execution of event method of PatternLayout, Am I rigth??

Comment: I do not fully understand your question, but the caller, for example LOG.debug calls from a thread, so the Thread I'd will be the one from the calling thread. Afaik, log4j itself does not use multithreading for the appenders, so I think it will work, ale the thread name would also not work..